# Python For Loop Count and Insert Numbers beside words

Tags: python

I have a problem regarding Python, I want to count the list item and then put a number beside the value of text.

This is the output I want:

```
test = 1
me = 2
texting = 3
```

This is the output I always get:

```
test = 3
me = 3
texting = 3
```

Here is my line of code:

```py
text =  request.form['title']
text2 = text.splitlines()
count = len(text2)
textarray = []
x = 0;
while(x <count):
    for txt in text2:
        textarray = [txt + " = " + str(x) for txt in text2]
    x = x+1
string = '<br>'.join(textarray)
return render_template('index.html', text=string)
```

Comment: You want to pair `value` with the words of the array ?

Comment: Also your code doesn't work, you can apply `splitlines` on a `list`

Comment: ` text2 = text.splitlines()` did you ever bother running this...you can't do splitlines on a list

Comment: `list(enumerate(text,1))` should do

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question and this is how should i put it. The entered value on text variable consist of 2 or more lines inside the textarea then submit.

Comment: note : If you use `splitlines` there will be NO remaining `\n`, as splitlines splits on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fix

You don't need 2 loops, just iterate over `text2` and increment your `x`n then append to the array, don't recreate it wit nonsense

```
textarray = []
x = 1
for txt in text2:
    textarray.append(txt + " = " + str(x))
    x = x + 1
```

---

#### Improve

Use `enumerate` to generate increasing value along with an iterable

```
textarray = []
for idx, txt in enumerate(text2, 1):
    textarray.append(f"{txt} = {idx}")
```

---

#### Best

Use generator construction and inline it

```
text = "test\nme\ntexting"

result = '</br>'.join(
    (f"{word}={idx}" for idx, word in enumerate(text.splitlines(), 1))
)

# return render_template('index.html', text=result)
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake for misunderstanding regarding the value variable, I mention the value inside the text variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, may i know what is the use of this "f"{word}={idx}" im new in python and haven't understand this code.

Comment: @mightypannkaka Look about `f-string` that is a nice and easy way to format python string since python 3.6

Comment: Is it okay to input if statement inside the for loop. For like if x == 2 then for loop stops?

Comment: @mightypannkaka yep but why so ? Why don’t you try and see if it satisfies you ?